# Unable to validate the form using jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have two sections on the same page and I need to validate the data on the first section that is why I am unable to use client side validation as it worked only after submitting the whole form.
So I have decided to use the jquery validation for validating the form.

Now, I want to validate this form on the section 1 `Next` button click. But, right now what is happening that when I click on the next button it just takes me to the second section without validating the data. Can someone please help me out what am I doing wrong here.

Anyone please correct me what am I doing wrong here or missing/wrongly used any references here. I need to validate the data before we go on section two.

```js
//password requirement script
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Passhash').keyup(function() {
    // set password variable
    var pswd = $('#Passhash').val();
    //validate the length
    if (pswd.length < 8) {
      $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      $('#length').removeClass('active');

    } else {
      $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      $('#length').addClass('active');

    }
    if (pswd.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/)) {
      $('#specialChar').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      $('#specialChar').removeClass('active');

    } else {
      $('#specialChar').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      $('#specialChar').addClass('active');
    }
    if (pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
      $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      $('#capital').addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      $('#capital').removeClass('active');
    }
    //validate number
    if (pswd.match(/\d/)) {
      $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      $('#number').addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      $('#number').removeClass('active');
    }
  }).focus(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').show();
  }).blur(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').hide();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nextCount = 1;
  $('#btnNext').click(function() {
    nextCount = nextCount + 1;
    var count = VeriFyEmail();
    var form = document.forms;
    $(form).validate({
      rules: {
        EmailId: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        YourName: {
          required: true,
        },
        CompanyName: {
          required: true,
        },
        PhoneNumber: {
          required: true
        },
        Passhash: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 8
        },
        ConfirmPassword: {
          required: true,
          equalTo: "#Passhash"
        }
      },
      messages: {
        EmailId: {
          required: "Please enter Email",
          email: "Please enter a valid Email"
        },
        YourName: {
          required: "Please enter YourName",
        },
        Passhash: {
          required: "Please enter password",
          minlength: "Password must be at least 8 characters long"
        },
        CompanyName: {
          required: "Please enter Company Name"
        },
        PhoneNumber: {
          required: "Please enter Phone Number"
        },
        ConfirmPassword: {
          required: "Please enter Confirm Password",
          equalTo: "Password and Confirm Password is different"
        }
      },

      submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert("Form Submitted Successfully")
      }
    });
    if (nextCount == 2) {
      $('#sectionSecond').show();
      $('#sectionFirst').hide();
      $('#btnBack').show();

      mailsend();
    } else if (nextCount == 2) {
      $('#sectionSecond').show();
      $('#sectionFirst').hide();

      $(this).hide();
      $('#btnSubmit').show();
    }

  });
  $('#btnBack').click(function() {
    nextCount = nextCount - 1;
    if (nextCount == 1) {
      $('#sectionFirst').show();
      $('#sectionSecond').hide();
      $('#btnBack').show();
      $('#btnSubmit').hide();
      $('#btnNext').show();
    }
    if (nextCount == 2) {
      $('#sectionSecond').show();
      $('#sectionFirst').hide();
      $('#btnBack').show();
      $('#btnSubmit').show();
      $('#btnNext').hide();
    } else if (nextCount == 2) {
      $('#sectionSecond').show();
      $('#sectionFirst').hide();

      $(this).hide();
      $('#btnSubmit').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
<script src="~/Content/bootstrap/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Xporta</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- IE Edge Meta Tag -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/style.css">
<script src="/Content/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form action="/Account/RegisterCompany" method="post">
  <section id="sectionFirst">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="main-div">
      <div class="row row1">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="div-left align-self-md-center">
            <div>
              <a href="index.html"><img src="/Content/images/logo.png" class="img-fluid img1" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <img src="/Content/images/img2.png" class="img-fluid img2" alt="">
            <div class="txt1">
              Fix your goals<br>
              <b>we’ll help you achieve!</b>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">

          <div class="div-right">
            <div>
              <a href="Login" class="back-btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Back</a>

              <ul>
                <li class="process-div active"></li>
                <li class="process-div"></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="txt2">General Information</div>
              <p class="txt3">Please share your primary email id and create password</p>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-custom" data-val="true" data-val-email="Invalid Email Address" data-val-required="EmailId Is Required" id="EmailId" name="EmailId" placeholder="Email ID *" type="text" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-custom" data-val="true" data-val-required="Your Name is required" id="YourName" name="YourName" placeholder="Your Name *" type="text" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control input-custom" data-val="true" data-val-required="Company Name is required" id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" placeholder="Company Name *" type="text" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-custom" data-val="true" data-val-required="Phone Number is required" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" placeholder="Mobile number *" type="text" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="ph">
                    <div class="form-group">

                      <input type="password" name="Passhash" class="form-control input-custom" id="Passhash" placeholder="Create Password *" autocomplete="new-password" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="pswd_info">
                      <ul class="password-list">
                        <li id="capital"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Atleast one capital letter</li>
                        <li id="specialChar"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Atleast one Special character</li>
                        <li id="number"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Atleast one Numeric digit</li>
                        <li id="length"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Minimum 8 digit</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control input-custom" id="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Re Enter Password *">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="msg-boxsucess1 txtsuccess" style="color:crimson; font-size:large">

            <span class="msg-boxsucess1 txtsuccess" id="emailError"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-section">

            <input type="button" id="btnNext" name="Next" class="btn-golden" value="Next" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="sectionSecond" style="display:none">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="main-div">
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: Your script src's indicate you are using [tag:jquery-validate] - I've updated the tags accordingly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

jquery validate plugin is only triggered when the form is *submitted*.  As you're not submitting the form, there's no form validation.

You need to call `.valid()` to manually trigger the validation, add

```
if (!$("form").valid()) return;
```

Note that your "second section" is also in the same form, so will also be validated.

Updated snippet with minor issues removed:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var nextCount = 1;
      $('#btnNext').click(function() {
        nextCount = nextCount + 1;
        var count = 1; //VeriFyEmail();
        var form = document.forms;
        $(form).validate({
          rules: {
            EmailId: {
              required: true,
              email: true
            },
            "YourName": {
              required: true,
            },
            CompanyName: {
              required: true,
            },
            PhoneNumber: {
              required: true
            },
            Passhash: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 8
            },
           
          },
          messages: {
            EmailId: {
              required: "Please enter Email",
              email: "Please enter a valid Email"
            },
            YourName: {
              required: "Please enter Your Name",
            },
            Passhash: {
              required: "Please enter password",
              minlength: "Password must be at least 8 characters long"
            },
            CompanyName: {
              required: "Please enter Company Name"
            },
            PhoneNumber: {
              required: "Please enter Phone Number"
            },
            ConfirmPassword: {
              required: "Please enter Confirm Password",
              equalTo: "Password and Confirm Password is different"
            }
          },

          submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert("Form Submitted Successfully")
          }
        });
        if (!$("form").valid()) return;
        if (nextCount == 2) {
          $('#sectionSecond').show();
          $('#sectionFirst').hide();
          $('#btnBack').show();
        } else if (nextCount == 2) {
          $('#sectionSecond').show();
          $('#sectionFirst').hide();

          $(this).hide();
          $('#btnSubmit').show();
        }

      });
      $('#btnBack').click(function() {
        nextCount = nextCount - 1;
        if (nextCount == 1) {
          $('#sectionFirst').show();
          $('#sectionSecond').hide();
          $('#btnBack').show();
          $('#btnSubmit').hide();
          $('#btnNext').show();
        }
        if (nextCount == 2) {
          $('#sectionSecond').show();
          $('#sectionFirst').hide();
          $('#btnBack').show();
          $('#btnSubmit').show();
          $('#btnNext').hide();
        } else if (nextCount == 2) {
          $('#sectionSecond').show();
          $('#sectionFirst').hide();

          $(this).hide();
          $('#btnSubmit').hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />


<form action="/Account/RegisterCompany" method="post">
  <section id="sectionFirst">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="main-div">
      <div class="row row1">

        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">

          <div class="div-right">
            <div>
              <div class="txt2">General Information</div>
              <p class="txt3">Please share your primary email id and create password</p>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-custom" data-val="true" data-val-email="Invalid Email Address" data-val-required="EmailId Is Required" id="EmailId" name="EmailId" placeholder="Email ID *" type="text" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-custom" data-val="true" data-val-required="Your Name is required" id="YourName" name="YourName" required='required' placeholder="Your Name *" type="text" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control input-custom" data-val="true" data-val-required="Company Name is required" id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" placeholder="Company Name *" type="text" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-custom" data-val="true" data-val-required="Phone Number is required" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" placeholder="Mobile number *" type="text" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="ph">
                    <div class="form-group">

                      <input type="password" name="Passhash" class="form-control input-custom" id="Passhash" placeholder="Create Password *" autocomplete="new-password" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="pswd_info">
                      <ul class="password-list">
                        <li id="capital"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Atleast one capital letter</li>
                        <li id="specialChar"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Atleast one Special character</li>
                        <li id="number"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Atleast one Numeric digit</li>
                        <li id="length"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Minimum 8 digit</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control input-custom" id="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Re Enter Password *">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="msg-boxsucess1 txtsuccess" style="color:crimson; font-size:large">

            <span class="msg-boxsucess1 txtsuccess" id="emailError"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-section">

            <input type="button" id="btnNext" name="Next" class="btn-golden" value="Next" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="sectionSecond" style="display:none">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="main-div2">
      Second Section
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank for clarifying it. It helps me a lot.